# Code using RISC-V a program that gives the largest value in a sequence

Tags: assembly, riscv

The question is:

Given a sequence of non-zero integers followed by 0, find the biggest integer
in the sequence and place the result in `x5`. 
Use the `DD` assembler command to store in the
beginning of the memory the initial test sequence of -1, 55, -3, 7, 0.

I have tried multiple variations of this:

```
src:    DD -1, 5, -3, 7, 0
        add x6, x0, x0
loop:   ld x5, src(x6)
        sd x7, dst(x6)
        beq x5, x0, end
        bge x5, x7, skip
skip:   addi x6, x6, 8
        beq x0, x0, loop
end:    ebreak x0, x0, 0
dst:    DM 1
```

however, nothing is working and I need some help on how to answer this question and how RISC-V works.

Comment: Your skip label doesn't skip anything, so move it further.

Comment: You don't want to store into the destination relative to x6, since it is a singleton, not an aggregate.

Comment: can you explain to me if i am on the right track because i am getting stuck trying to iterate through the sequence because i understand how to code this is java but RISC-V is not making sense to me

Comment: You don't need 3 branch instructions in the loop, only 2 (1 inside the loop to update max, another at the bottom which falls through after the last iteration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your intended use of the registers is:

- `x5` contains the *current value read from the sequence*.
- `x6` contains the *index into the sequence*.
- `x7` contains the *maximum value seen so far*.

---

There is no need to store `x7` in memory since the maximum value is a single value at any moment. The register `x7` should be initialized at the very beginning.

`x7` could be initialized with the lowest possible value it can hold, i.e., *-2<sup>63</sup>*:

```
addi x7, x0, 1
slli x7, x7, 63
```

Any value read from the sequence other than this lowest possible value would cause the current maximum to be updated.

Alternatively, you can directly load the first element of the sequence into `x7` since there is always one element available for loading (the terminating `0` if it's an empty sequence):

```
ld x7, sr(x6)
```

---

The following branch instruction in your code:

```
        bge x5, x7, skip
skip:   addi x6, x6, 8
```

Regardless of whether or not the condition holds (`x5` *>=* `x7`), the next instruction executed is always `addi x6, x6, 8`. What is missing between these two instructions, after the `skip` label, is the code for updating the current maximum value seen so far, i.e., an instruction for moving the contents from `x5` to `x7`. The operands `x5` and `x7` of the `bge` instruction must also be swapped since you want to *skip* the code for updating the maximum when `x7` *>=* `x5` holds (i.e., the maximum isn't updated when the *maximum* is already greater or equal to the *current value*):

```
        bge x7, x5, skip # skip the update of the maximum?
        addi x7, x5, 0   # update new maximum value
skip:   addi x6, x6, 8
```

Therefore, if the branching condition does hold, i.e., if `x7` (the maximum) is *greater or equal* to `x5` (the current value read), the code for updating the maximum is skipped.

---

Instead of having two branch instruction in the loop: the `beq x5, x0, end` that terminates the loop if the zero value has been reached in the sequence, and the unconditional jump `beq x0, x0, loop` as the last instruction of your loop for repeating the loop, you could rearrange your code so that the loop's last instruction is:

```
bne x5, x0, loop   # is the end of the sequence not reached yet?
```

This would replace both `beq x5, x0, end` and `beq x0, x0, loop`: if the terminating value of the sequence (i.e., zero) has been reached it falls through, otherwise, it iterates the loop again.

---

Keeping all these things in mind, your code could look like:

```
src:    DD -1, 5, -3, 7, 0

        add x6, x0, x0      # initialize the index
        ld x7, sr(x6)       # initialize the maximum
        addi x5, x7, 0      # initialize with the first value

        beq x5, x0, end     # is the sequence empty?

loop:   bge x7, x5, skip    # skip the update of the maximum?
        addi x7, x5, 0      # update the maximum with the new value read
skip:   addi x6, x6, 8      # update the index
        ld x5, sr(x6)       # load the next value from the sequence
        bne x5, x0, loop    # is the end of the sequence not reached yet?        
end:    
        addi x5, x7, 0      # place the final result in x5 (your problem's assignment)
        ebreak x0, x0, 0
```

Comment: The array is implicit-length so it's always safe to load the first element.  You could use that instead of constructing INT64_MIN with 2 regs.  The return value is meaningless anyway if there are no elements before the terminator.  That might also be a good setup for peeling the first iteration so you can put the loop-exit conditional branch at the bottom of the loop where it belongs.

Comment: I think you introduced a bug.  You now check `x5` for being a new max before you check it for being a terminator.  I'd put ld + bne near the bottom, with a jump to there to enter the loop.  Or peel part of the first iteration so you can just fall into the loop.   (i.e. check if the main part of the loop body needs to run 0 times, and skip the loop if that's the case.  Like normal for a loop that might need to run 0 times.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, you are right. However, if I put the `ld`+`bne` sequence at the end of the loop, it will load one element past the end if the sequence it's empty. I solve it by placing a `beq x5, x0, end` just before entering the loop. Thank you.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was describing in the last part of my comment: branch to skip the whole loop before falling into a normal do{}while loop structure.  Now you also avoid loading the first element twice.

Comment: thanks for the help it really cleared things up for me

Comment: @HaniSalehi: If this answer fully answers your question, you can accept it by clicking the check-mark under the up/down vote arrows.

Comment: BTW, for performance you'd probably want to write the loop so the normal case (no new maximum) is a not-taken branch.  Taken branches can have more costs than not-taken even when predicted correctly, especially on a superscalar CPU.  So for example you could conditionally jump to another block (after the end of the function) which updates `x7` and jumps back. Possibly duplicate the loop tail so you can fall through (to a jump to `end`, or to a duplicated end of the whole function that returns). Or jump directly to `loop` after setting up for the next iteration if we didn't load the terminator.

Comment: if RISC-V has an efficient predicated "conditional move" instruction, this would be a good use-case.  (One conditional move instead of a conditional branch over a move)